# How do I give credit to some image I included in my paper?

Tags: citations

I recreated an image from a paper I liked (didn't use the same image to get out of the asking permission which could take a while). Now the reviewer asked us to give credit to the original paper. How do I do that? Is it okay to write that my image was 'inspired' from this other paper, as I didn't copy the image but used the image as a reference to create my own?

Its a drawing of blood vessels (with appropriate details related to our work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all,

> permission which could take a while

Is not entirely correct. Most major publishers have an automated "permission request" system that in many cases automatically grants you permission to reuse a figure from a published paper. It takes about 5 minutes and usually you can find it in the journal's home page.

> Now the reviewer asked us to give credit to the original paper. How do I do that?

This isn't too hard. One way, for instance, would be to add to the figure caption: "**Redrawn after Smith et al. (2005)**". I think it also depends on what the figure is about. Is it a graph with data points that you used? Is it some schematic drawing? If you edit your question to better describe the figure we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Its a biological drawing. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, modifying an image does *not* overcome copyright protection and the need to get permission. Making a modification to someone else's image requires copying it, and the copyright owner is the one who has the right to allow copying.

Comment: This answer is not relevant because the image was not copied. The author states very clearly "...I didn't copy the image but used the image as a reference to create my own..."

Comment: I disagree: "copy" is not limited to exact reproduction under copyright law.